# Deleting All Rows That Have an Empty "B" Column Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to create a macro that deletes all rows that don't contain any data in Column B. Any help would be appreciated. This is all I got for now.

```
Sub DeleteAllEmptyBRows()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Range("B1:B" & lr)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Row.Delete
            Exit Sub
        End If
   Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SpecialCells` to do this in one quick line:

`Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

I'd use the above, but also for your own knowledge, here's how you could do it following your code:

```
Sub DeleteAllEmptyBRows()
Dim lr As Long, i&

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1 'Since you're deleting rows, start at the end, and work upwards
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Note that you have an `Exit Sub` in yours, after the first time a row is deleted. I removed that, since you want to loop through all cells in the range.  Again, this is a loop so will take longer, and has more room for errors, than the simple one liner above.

Comment: Realized I forgot to thank you. This is perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some parameters:

```
Cells(cell.Row, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

If you need the entire row, just change to:

```
cell.Row.EntireRow.Delete
```